# Unable to login adminstrator account

Tags: boot, login, shutdown, root, guest-session

I don't know what I have done exactly before it happen, the last thing I have done is accepting to install upadtes and to program it to shutdown after it finishes using sudo shutdown -h [MM]...

After booting it and realizing the problem listed below (maybe one day later) I booted with a live USB, it had an extremely long time to boot, had to force shutdown and retry.

Now I can't login to my account (when I enter the right password, it logs but there isn't any change: the same default background, and not a single element in the desktop, I have changed the cursor to black, which doesn't change in this case).

I can only use guest mode, I have access to recovery mode but if I chose "root" mode, the same thing happens.

Sorry for my bad english and thank you for helping.

Edit: I'm on Lubuntu 14. I'm going to update it anyways (or change the OS) so I just need to recover >100Gb of data.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

You boot into recovery mode.

Select in this order the submenu

```
fsck
dpkg
network
root
```

In a terminal, run it:

```
sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
reboot
```

Comment: Thank you so much, kyodake. It takes a lot of time and overheats the PC, so I tried to boot from a live CD (or install one without uninstalling Lubuntu), in this case Trisquel mini, and it works, I can have root access, but I can't access home folder, if there's a possibility to do so (and to move data to an external hard drive) thank you for answering.